# Lost directory is using space. How do I find, and delete it

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, lubuntu, gparted, disk-usage

Please some help with this, to this point I have tried everything I know.

I have a virtual machine that I use to work. On this machine I have Ubuntu. This guy started with a 30GB disk the became full very easily. SO I made another 8GB virtual drive, and I copied on this one all the HOME folder, after this I changed the configuration to recognize this drive as the /home and it works perfect.

But have the feeling that the /home folder on the original drive is still there using 15GB of space.

My Gparted shows me a 30GB drive 90% full, but QDirStat and Baobab show only 15 GB of used space on the drive.

How do I recover this space?

[image: Gparted]
[image: QDirStat]
[image: Baobab]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unmount /home and then run QDirStat again. You may find that /home still contains a lot of files that were shadowed by that other /home you mounted on top of that filesystem.

Whenever you mount another filesystem, make sure you mount it to a directory that doesn't contain anything since any previous content of that directory will become invisible once any other filesystem is mounted there.

*Update 2021-03-24: Wrote a document describing the procedure and a script for the common case:* https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/Shadowed-by-Mount.md

Kind regards

Stefan Hundhammer (HuHa)

QDirStat Author

Comment: Amazing beautiful software, I love it. 
Can I run it as SU, cant find a way.

Comment: I actually found the problem thanks to QDirStat. It was hiding in plain sight. the directory was not shadowed. but hiding inside the root folder, I don't know why. 
After running qdirstat as roo I found the dam folder hidden.

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't mount another filesystem on top of an existing populated directory.  You might have to manually merge new home dirs with old home dirs... it can get messy.  You are right that if you copied the contents... instead of moving them... the data is still there.  You could kick all the users off... switch to single-user-mode (root only) unmount the volume on top of /home... delete the contents of /home (or move to somewhere else for archiving purposes)... remount the disk... and all should be happy again.

Comment: let me check, sound fine. NO other users, its  VM used for development only by me.

Comment: I got to the part where I unmount the device, but I can't find the old folder, how should I do that

Comment: once unmounted... the existing directory should be exactly where it is. i.e. /home